# How to get element within range for nested list

Tags: python, replace, nested-lists

Just started learning python, I have this assignment where I need do range within nested list.

```
tlist = [['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4], ['Zen', 'No', 90, 1]]
```

I want to ask for the low and higher value for tlist[2]

```
low = int(input("Enter low")) #take this as 1
high = int(input("Enter High")) #take this as 50
```

this need to be updated and when I call the list again it should show, and remove 'zen' from the list

```
tlist = [['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code. Try to iterate over the list with condition including low and high

```
tlist = [['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4], ['Zen', 'No', 90, 1]]
low = int(input("Enter low")) #take this as 1
high = int(input("Enter High")) #take this as 50
tlist = [l for l in tlist if l[2]>=low and l[2]<=high]
print(tlist)
```

Comment: Or simply `[l for l in tlist if low <= l[2] <= high]`.

Answer (score -1):

## Method 1 : Keeping `tlist` unchanged and saving result to another list.

- Loop through each inner list in `t_list`
- Access the third element at index 2 in each inner list.
- Check if this element in the range `[low,high]`.
- If yes, add current inner list to new list.

```py
tlist = [['Foo', 'No', 80, 1], ['Bar', 'No', 90, 1], ['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4], ['Zen', 'No', 90, 1]] 
updated_list = []
low = 1
high = 50

for inner_list in tlist:
    if inner_list[2] >= low and inner_list[2] <= high:
        updated_list.append(inner_list)

print(updated_list)
# [['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4]]
```

## Method 2 : Using remove() to directly modify `tlist`

```py
tlist = [['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4], ['Zen', 'No', 90, 1]]
low = 1
high = 50
for i in range(len(tlist)-1,-1,-1):
    inner_list = tlist[i]
    if inner_list[2] < low or inner_list[2] > high:
        tlist.remove(inner_list)
print(tlist)
# [['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4]]
```

When `tlist = [['Foo', 'No', 80, 1], ['Bar', 'No', 90, 1], ['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4], ['Zen', 'No', 90, 1]]`, output is :

```
[['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4]]
```

**Note** : The concern expressed in the comments has been resolved by iterating from the end of the list instead of the beginning. The re-indexing caused by `remove()` no longer affects the final answer.

Comment: Changing the size of the list while iterating over it may cause unexpected problems. You should create a copy of the list for iteration.

Comment: Try running this code with: *tlist = [['Foo', 'No', 80, 1], ['Bar', 'No', 90, 1], ['Josh', 'Yes', 1, 4], ['Amy', 'No', 30, 4], ['Zen', 'No', 90, 1]]* and note that the 'Bar' element doesn't get removed

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I modified my code accordingly.